# How to use two queries in the same php file

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

Is it possible to query two different tables from the same php file.
It does work if I run one INSERT only but with two I cannot get it work. Why? Whats the way to use 2 INSERT statement in the same PHP page and add the information in two different tables?

```
 <?php
include("../includes/connection.php");
 
// Escape user inputs for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['number']);
$device = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['device']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
$payment = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['payment']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['status']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['model']);
$problem = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['problem']);
 
// attempt insert query execution
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (mail, number, device, price, paymenttype,status,date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number', '$device', '$price', '$payment','$status',NOW())";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    // echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("location:ciao.php?message=The customer has been added to the database");

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table2(model, problem, device, status) VALUES ('$model', '$problem', '$device', '$status')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    // echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("location:ciao.php?message=The customer has been added to the database");

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: You closed the connection when you executed the first insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check your first query syntax. It should be like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(mail, number, device, price, paymenttype,status,date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number', '$device', '$price', '$payment','$status',NOW())";
```

2) You have closed the connection before second insert query.

Comment: query sintax was ok, i just deleted for mistake the parentesis when i changed the name of the table. the main problem was  that I closed the connection before second insert query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your first insert query as

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, mail, number, device, price, paymenttype,status,date) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$number', '$device', '$price', '$payment','$status',NOW())";
```

Second you **close the connection before second insert query**. Just comment close connection. And try to give different variable name in second insert

```
  //  mysqli_close($link);// comment this line

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2(model, problem, device, status) VALUES ('$model', '$problem', '$device', '$status')";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
    // echo "Records added successfully.";
    header("location:ciao.php?message=The customer has been added to the database");

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql1. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 1):

You closed the connection when you executed the first insert, and when you use the connection from the second one the connection is already close